# Do quantum logic gates have propagation delay like classic logic gates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Classic logic gates that are usually constructed using conventional semiconductor technology are subject to propagation delay, which means it takes some time for the output of a gate to reflect on its inputs.

Is that the case for quantum logic gates too? Is there a way to construct quantum logic gates, such as CNOT, with no propagation delay, for example using entanglement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrying out quantum gates (quantum operations) takes time. Otherwise, we could run computations in zero time.

Comment: Thanks. So does this rule out the possibility of “spooky action”? I mean can we not make quantum gates whose outputs are entangled with their inputs so changes in inputs instantaneously change the outputs?